# Google Cloud list all users in a project when assigned by group permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-iam

Instead of adding users directly to a project we are adding them to groups which are then assigned permissions.

When using commands like: `gcloud projects get-iam-policy MY_PROJECT` it returns the name of the group and service accounts within the project.

What command can I run to return users within each group?

Thank you,
Ari

Comment: Which service are you using for group management (G Suite, Cloud Identity, or Google Groups)?